# Why my pojo can't be managed in spring-container?

Tags: java, spring

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tzuIY.png)

My pojo were packaged in common module and I import them in a new module. Then,this problem happened when spring creates proxy-bean of that interface. I'm confused.

Comment: Add the code here for reference. How you are using pojo in repositories.

Comment: Paste the full related codes, not just an image of the error.

Comment: This problem  results from spring-data-jpa which haven't configured entity-database mapping.

Comment: • Welcome to StackOverflow! Please avoid uploading code as an image.
https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.